# Image is getting broken when called at frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, multiselect-attribute

In magento1.9.2.4 when I created `multiple select` attribute with options and images for those options are placed in `skin/frontend/<my_package>/<my_theme>/images/` and called the attribute in `list.phtml` like

```
 <?php
  $Feature = explode(",",$_product->getResource()
  ->getAttribute('feature')->getFrontend()
  ->getValue($_product));

 foreach($Feature as $key => $value): ?>

<?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN)."frontend/<package_name>/<theme_name>/images/".$value.".png'/>"; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now only the first image of the option is displaying. Other images are broken. When I Inspected the element in browser there was space before the image name.
am not able to figure out the mistake. Kindly help me please.

Also when the image is clicked it should redirect to the respective product details page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not getting the exact problem but if you are facing the space issue then use `trim()` function to remove extra spaces as:

```
<?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN)."frontend/<package_name>/<theme_name>/images/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
```